# How to avoid the automatic generate </br> tag when using Table into WordPress Plugin Editor

Tags: php, wordpress, events, plugins

I am using the WordPress Event plus plugin and this plugin has a editor where 
put event detail. When I am using table then I see the event detail on the browser 
automatically so many `</br>` generated automatically before the table content.

But when I am using the table into the WordPress editor then No `</br>` is generated data is showing properly.

How to avoid this type of problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may be your code is like this

```
<div>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting,</div>

remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with 

<span>desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</span>
```

if yes please remove all enter like this

```
<div>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting,</div>remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with<span>desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</span>
```